# how to update postgresql rows using php?

Tags: php, postgresql

first I want to say that I'm a beginner in postgresql and php.. my company told me to create a database that they can view and edit on local server.. so I created the database in postgresql.. created a page that views the database:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ongoing projects</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="666657">
<?php
//database access information
require_once("DB.php");
$host = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "";
$db = "Project_list";
$port = "5432";

//open a connection to the database server
$connection = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass port=$port");
if (!$connection)
{
die("Could not open connection to database server");
}

?>


<?php


$query = 'select * from ongoing';
$result = pg_query($query); $i = 0;


echo '<html><table bgcolor="666657" width="10" height="30" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><td align="center"> <h1><font color = "#ffb200"> Ongoing projects</h1>';

 echo '<html><body><table border= 2 BORDERCOLOR="000000" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0"> <tr >';


while ($i < pg_num_fields($result)) {
$fieldName =pg_field_name($result, $i);
echo '<b>'.'<td width="2" bgcolor="666657" align="center">'.'<font color = "#ffb200">'. '</b>'.'<b>'. $fieldName . '</b>'. '</td>';
$i = $i + 1; }
 echo("<td><align= center><font color = #ffb200><b>Action</td>");

echo '</tr>' ;
$i = 0;

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
echo '<tr align="center" width="1">';
$count = count($row);
$y = 0;
while ($y < $count) {
$c_row = current($row);
echo '<td>' .'<font color = "#ffb200">'. $c_row . '</td>';

next($row);

$y = $y + 1;
}
echo("<td><align= center><a href='editongoing.php?ProjectID=".$row[0]."'>Edit</a></td>");
echo '</tr>';
$i = $i + 1;
}


pg_free_result($result);

echo '</table></body></html>';

?>
<h3>
<a href="projects.php"</a>Back to projects page</a>

</h3>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
if (window.print) {

document.write('<form> '
+ '<input type=button name=print value="Click" '
+ 'onClick="javascript:window.print()"> To Print!</form>');
}
// End -->
</script>
```

when you click the edit button, you will go to this page where you can edit the raw you want, this is the (edit)  code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit Ongoing projects</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="666657">

<?php
// attempt a connection
$connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=Project_list user=admin password=");
if (!$connection) {
die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
}
if ($_REQUEST['ProjectID']!=''){

$QueryStr = "Select * from ongoing where project_no='".$_REQUEST['ProjectID']."'";
$result = pg_query($connection, $QueryStr);
if (!$result) {
die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
}
$row = pg_fetch_row($result);

print_r($row);

}
if ($_POST['submit']) {


// escape strings in input data
$project_no = pg_escape_string($_POST['project_no']);
$title = pg_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$duration = pg_escape_string($_POST['duration']);
$manager = pg_escape_string($_POST['manager']);
$country = pg_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$total_fee = pg_escape_string($_POST['totalfee']);
$performed = pg_escape_string($_POST['performed']);
$remaining = pg_escape_string($_POST['remaining']);
$gross_profit = pg_escape_string($_POST['gross_profit']);
$gp = pg_escape_string($_POST['gp']);
$performance_year = pg_escape_string($_POST['performance_year']);
$gp_year = pg_escape_string($_POST['gp_year']);


// execute query
$sql = "INSERT INTO ongoing (project_no, project_title, duration, manager, country, total_fee,
performed, remaining, gross_profit, gp, performance_year, gp_year)
VALUES('$project_no', '$title', '$duration', '$manager', '$country','$total_fee','$performed','$remaining',
'$gross_profit','$gp', '$performance_year','$gp_year')";
$result = pg_query($connection, $sql);
f (!$result) {
die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
}

echo "Data successfully inserted!";


// free memory
pg_free_result($result);

// close connection
pg_close($connection);
}
?>

<form action= "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"><b><font color = "#ffb200">
Project No.: <br>  <input id="project_no" type="text" name="project_no" size="20" value=<?= $row[0] ?>>
<p>
Project Title: <br> <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value='<?= $row[1] ?>'>
<p>
Duration: <br> <input ID="duration" type="text" name="duration" value=<?= $row[2] ?>>
<p>
Project Manager: <br> <input ID="manager" type="text" name="manager" value=<?= $row[3] ?>>
<p>
Country: <br> <input ID="country" type="text" name="country"  value=<?= $row[4] ?>>
 <p>
Total Fee: <br> <input ID="totalfee" type="text" name="total_fee" value=<?= $row[5] ?>>
 <p>
Already performed: <br> <input ID="performed" type="text" name="performed" value=<?= $row[6] ?>>
 <p>
Remaining performance: <br> <input ID="remaining" type="text" name="remaining" value=<?= $row[7] ?>>
 <p>
Gross Profit: <br> <input ID="gross_profit" type="text" name="gross_profit" value='<?= $row[8] ?>'>
<p>
GP%: <br> <input ID="gp" type="text" name="gp" value=<?= $row[9] ?>>
<p>
Performance actual year: <br> <input ID="performance_year" type="text" name="performance_year" value=<?= $row[10] ?>>
<p>
GP actual year: <br> <input ID="gp_year" type="text" name="gp_year" value=<?= $row[11] ?>>
<p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sumbit my table" size="30">

<P>
<a href="ongoing.php"</a>View ongoing projects</a>
<a href="editproject.php"</a>Back to editing menu</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, when I edit the data and click on submit my table, a new raw is inserted.. but I want it to be updated not inserted... help plz

Answer (score 2):

You need to select which record (id number) you want to update, and then your query will look like

`$sql = "UPDATE ongoing SET field1='value', field2='value' ... WHERE id = 'id of project you want to edit'";`